# Does Golang need to listen and serve on the same port as the server?

Tags: go

I've built a little web app in go but on a server you can`t launch and listen to a serve function because the server is already on a port.

Do I need to listen and serve but set it on the same port that the server runs? In python, for example, you have a virtualenv. Does go require a similar environment?

Comment: What do you mean by "the server is already on a port"?

Comment: for example if you have a vagrantbox ,the box is served on localhost port 8000

Comment: Ok, so @Rob answer is correct, on a server two processes can't listen on the same port, you have to use another one.

Answer (score 2):

When you use Go's built in server, it's no different than listening with Apache or nginx. You can listen on any IP and port you wish but you have to avoid conflicts where both attempt to respond to the same requests. If your server is listening on 127.0.0.1:80, you can't have Go listening in on the same port or there will be a conflict (for example).